# What is the difference between Time-Frequency Represenation and TF Decomposition

Tags: wavelet, convolution, decomposition

I'm asking as I'm looking at Wavelet transforms, and I see that it is possible to have a TF decomposition or a representation of the signal.

Looking for example at the code [here](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/blob/master/mne/time_frequency/tfr.py) we can see that the TF representation
([tfr_morlet function](https://github.com/mne-tools/mne-python/blob/master/mne/time_frequency/tfr.py#L861))of a signal returns the averaged power and optionally the intertrial coherence.

The TF decomposition function (cwt_morlet, line 167) on the other hand returns Time Frequency Decompositions (n_signals x n_frequencies x n_times) arrays.

What does each process do in this sense?